# CORS Error Despite Setting Response Headers in Flask

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, axios, cors

I have a flask endpoint hosted on localhost:5000 that I am trying to send requests to from a React app hosted on localhost:3000. The endpoint looks like this:

```
@app.route('/createUserSession', methods=["POST", "OPTIONS", "GET"])
@cross_origin()
def createUserSession():
    response = Response()
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "http://localhost:3000"
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = ["GET", "POST", "OPTIONS"]
    response.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"] = "true"
    return response
```

I call it from the frontend using axios as follows:

```
const api = axios.create({
        withCredentials: false,
        crossorigin: true
      });
api.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/createUserSession', queryString.stringify(params),
        {headers: headers})
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

I tried various permutations of the headers, and each time get the CORS error telling me either the origin is not allowed or the credentials header is set to false. Is there any solution beyond using a proxy? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"` ?

Comment: Why not set [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) in the package.json. I assume both server and client code are going to be hosted on the same domain in production. Adding cors on the server only opens the server up to abuse from other sites.

Comment: I tried `response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*"`, and I also tried adding "proxy":"localhost:5000" in the package.json of my frontend. Still getting CORS error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Flask-CORS (https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Initialize the Flask-CORS where you have initialized the Flask application. The simple use case as stated in the Flask-CORS official documentation in the context of your code is:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/createUserSession": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route("/createUserSession")
def createUserSession():
  return "user session response"
```

It's always better to have prefixes in API endpoints so that similar types of endpoints can be grouped together. For instance, you can change your endpoint to `@app.route("/api/createUserSession")`

After using this your CORS instance would be `cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})`, making it easier to cover other API endpoints with prefix /api in the same instance of CORS